# Illustrator Script: Invrting Fill/Opacity

Tags: javascript, opacity, adobe-illustrator

I am new to JavaScript, but looking to create a script that will take the value of the fill when a halftone is set and apply that value to the opacity.  Once the opacity value has been adjusted, I need the fill to reset to 100(full).

The most helpful code I've seen so far was in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899229/illustrator-extendscript-set-fill-opacity-of-selection) article, and I've tried adjusting several ways to be consistent with some of the other scripts I use for consistency as seen here:

```
    doc = app.activeDocument;
    i = 0
    var selection = activeDocument.pageItems[i];
    var storedColor = activeDocument.pageItems[i].fillColor;

    //apply value of stored color of individual selection to opacity
    selection.opacity = storedColor[i];
    selection.fillColor = 100;
```

This seems like it should be reasonably simple if I was clearer on what I was doing.  Any help or code adjustments would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to streamline some of the steps used in my business.

Thank you!

Comment: Its not clear in your question what is going wrong for you. Can you describe what is not working for you?

Comment: Right now, when I run the script nothing happens.  Fills stay at whatever they are at originally, and opacity does the same.  I'm looking for a solution that will allow the script to run/function.  Not sure if it's the Program versioning, I'm using Illustrator 17 (Creative Cloud).